# This program always output a score and minus 5,Can you help me?

Tags: c

```
printf("\nDirection: Choose the letter of the correct answer");
printf("\n \n1. What is the REAL name of BILL GATES?");
printf("\nA. William Henry Bill Gates III \tB.Steve Jobs  \tC. William Henry Bill Gates  \tD. William Henry Bill Gates II");
printf("\nAnswer?");
scanf("%s", &answer1);
if (answer1 == 'A' || answer1 == 'a') score++;
else;
score;
printf("\n2. Bill Gates was born in?");
printf("\nA.Washington DC \tB. Seattle, Washington \tC. United States of America \tD. Los Angles, California");
printf("\nAnswer?");
scanf("%s", &answer2);
if (answer2 == 'B' || answer2 == 'b') score++;
else;
score;
printf("\n3. Who was the Co-Founder of Windows?");
printf("\nA. Ray Allen \tB. Paul Allen  \tC. Patrick Allen \tD. Leandro Allen");
printf("\nAnswer?");
scanf("%s", &answer3);
if (answer3 == 'B' || answer3 == 'b') score++;
else;
score;
printf("\n4. When did the first WINDOWS launched?");
printf("\nA. December 20, 1985 \tB. October 20, 1985 \tC. November 20, 1985 \tD. December 31, 1998");
printf("\nAnswer?");
scanf("%s", &answer4);
if (answer4 == 'C' || answer4 == 'c') score++;
else;
score;
printf("\n5. What is the REAL name of STEVE JOBS?");
printf("\nA. Steven Paul  Jobs \tB. Paul Leandro Lanot \tC. Steven Paul Jobs II \tD. Steve Paul Jobs");
printf("\nAnswer?");
scanf("%s", &answer5);
if (answer5 == 'A' || answer5 == 'a') score++;
else;
score;
printf("\n6. Three states of matter.");
printf("\nA.density, volume and weight  \tB. solid, liquid, and gas \tC. water, metal and gases \tD. water, air and gases");
printf("\nAnswer?");
scanf("%s", &answer6);
if (answer6 == 'B' || answer6 == 'b') score++;
else;
score;
printf("\n7. The temperature at which a substance changes from a liquid to a gas.");
printf("\nA. Freezing point   \tB. Melting point \tC.Boiling point \tD. Condensation point");
printf("\nAnswer?");
scanf("%s", &answer7);
if (answer7 == 'C' || answer7 == 'c') score++;
else;
score;
printf("\n8.The temperature at which a substance changes from a liquid to a solid");
printf("\nA. Freezing point \tB.Boiling point \tC. Melting point \tD. Condensation point");
printf("\nAnswer?");
scanf("%s", &answer8);
if (answer8 == 'A' || answer8 == 'a') score++;
else;
score;
printf("\n9. Anything that has definite volume but no definite shape.");
printf("\nA.  Solid  \tB. Metal \tC. Liquid \tD. Gas");
printf("\nAnswer?");
scanf("%s", &answer9);
if (answer9 == 'B' || answer9 == 'b') score++;
else;
score;
printf("\n10. The amount of space something takes up.");
printf("\nA. Density \tB. Volume \tC. Mass \tD. Length");
printf("\nAnswer?");
scanf("%s", &answer10);
if (answer10 == 'B' || answer10 == 'b') score++;
else;
score;
printf("\n11. The temperature at which a substance changes from a gas to liquid.");
printf("\nA. boiling point \tB. condensation point \tC. freezing point \tD. melting point");
printf("\nAnswer?");
scanf("%s", &answer11);
if (answer11 == 'B' || answer11 == 'b') score++;
else;
score;
printf("\n12. The temperature at which a substance changes from a solid to a liquid.");
printf("\nA. Condensation point \tB. boiling point \tC. freezing point \tD. Melting point");
printf("\nAnswer?");
scanf("%s", &answer12);
if (answer12 == 'D' || answer12 == 'd') score++;
else;
score;
printf("\n13. Which of Newton's Three Laws does the following statement satisfy? For every action there is an equal and opposite reaction.");
printf("\nA. Newton's First Law \tB. Newton's Second Law \tC. Newton's Third Law \tD. All of the above");
printf("\nAnswer?");
scanf("%s", &answer13);
if (answer13 == 'C' || answer13 == 'c') score++;
else;
score;
printf("\n14. Which of Newton's Three Laws does the following statement satisfy? Every object in a state of uniform motion tends to remain in that state of motion unless an external force is applied to it.");
printf("\nA. Newton's First Law \tB. Newton's Second Law \tC. Newton's Third Law \tD.  All of the above");
printf("\nAnswer?");
scanf("%s", &answer14);
if (answer14 == 'A' || answer14 == 'a') score++;
else;
score;
printf("\n15. Which of Newton's three laws does the following example illustrate? If you have a hockey puck sliding along a table, it will eventually come to a stop.");
printf("\nA. Newton's First Law \tB. Newton's Second Law \tC. Newton's Third Law \tD.  All of the above");
printf("\nAnswer?");
scanf("%s", &answer15);
if (answer15 == 'A' || answer15 == 'a') score++;
else;
score;
printf("\n16. In the following example, what are the forces that are acting on the ball? Check all that apply. If a ball is thrown in the air, it will keep going the same velocity unless a force changes the velocity (speed and direction).");
printf("\nA. air friction \tB. gravity \tC. resistance of the ground \tD. all of the above");
printf("\nAnswer?");
scanf("%s", &answer16);
if (answer16 == 'D' || answer16 == 'd') score++;
else;
score;
printf("\n17. Which law states the need to wear seatbelts?");
printf("\nA. Newton's First Law \tB. Newton's Second Law \tC. Newton's Third Law \tD.  None of the above");
printf("\nAnswer?");
scanf("%s", &answer17);
if (answer17 == 'A' || answer17 == 'a') score++;
else;
score;
printf("\n18.What is another name for the Newton's first law of motion?");
printf("\nA.Law of Acceleration \tB.Law of Velocity \tC.Law of Inertia \tD.Law of Mass");
printf("\nAnswer?");
scanf("%s", &answer18);
if (answer18 == 'C' || answer18 == 'c') score++;
else;
score;
printf("\n19.Which of Newton's Three Law does the following example illustrate? The blood in your head rushes to your feet when riding on an elevator this is descending and abruptly stops. ");
printf("\nA. Newton's First Law \tB. Newton's Second Law \tC. Newton's Third Law \tD.  None of the above");
printf("\nAnswer?");
scanf("%s", &answer19);
if (answer19 == 'A' || answer19 == 'a') score++;
else;
score;
printf("\n20. A triangle with one angle greater than 90 degrees.");
printf("\nA. equilateral triangle \tB. obtuse triangle \tC. acute triangle \tD. isosceles triangle");
printf("\nAnswer?");
scanf("%s", &answer20);
if (answer20 == 'B' || answer20 == 'b') score++;
else;
score;
printf("\n21. A triangle with all three angles less than 90 degrees.");
printf("\nA. equilateral triangle \tB. obtuse triangle \tC. acute triangle \tD. isosceles triangle");
printf("\nAnswer?");
scanf("%s", &answer21);
if (answer21 == 'C' || answer21 == 'c') score++;
else;
score;
printf("\n22.A triangle with one angle equal to 90 degrees.");
printf("\nA.right triangle \tB.equilateral triangle \tC. acute triangle \tD. isosceles triangle");
printf("\nAnswer?");
scanf("%s", &answer22);
if (answer22 == 'A' || answer22 == 'a') score++;
else;
score;
printf("\n23.A triangle having three equal sides.");
printf("\nA. equilateral triangle \tB. obtuse triangle \tC. acute triangle \tD. right triangle");
printf("\n23.Answer?");
scanf("%s", &answer23);
if (answer23 == 'D' || answer23 == 'd') score++;
else;
score;
printf("\n24.The sum of the measures of all three sides of a triangle.");
printf("\nA.area \tB. perimeter \tC. diameter \tD.none of the above");
printf("\nAnswer?");
scanf("%s", &answer24);
if (answer24 == 'B' || answer24 == 'b') score++;
else;
score;
printf("\n25.In right triangle, the side opposite to right angle is called");
printf("\nA. altitude \tB.hypotenuse \tC. angle bisector \tD.none of the above");
printf("\nAnswer?");
scanf("%s", &answer25);
if (answer25 == 'B' || answer25 == 'b') score++;
else;
score;

printf("\n\t\tTEST Score=%d", score);
```

Comment: Ctrl+A -> Delete and start over.

Comment: why? does it have any problem? :( can you teach it to me :(

Comment: Remove all `else;` and `score;`, these are completely useless. Initialize score with 0. Better use fgets instead of scanf in this case, it makes things a bit more robust here. And use a single answer-buffer, there is no need to have one for each answer.

Comment: Each `answerX=='A'` should have generated a warning, no?

Comment: Show the definitions for all local variables.  There is a good chance `score` is not initialized or is overwritten by `scanf` reading single char variables with a `%s` format.

Comment: answer5 is probably a char, so no. I would suggest to have one `char answer[10];`, do `fgets(answer, sizeof(answer), stdin);` and check with `if (*answer=='x' || *answer=='X') ...`

Comment: what do you mean single answer-buffer? sorry I am just a student.

Comment: Not answer1-answer25, but one `answer[]` which is reused. Unless you really need the answers later on, but even then better use an array.

Comment: Can my array is like this answer[1]?

Comment: @PaulLanot: all the answer arrays should single chars: `char answerxx;` but read with `scanf( "%c", &answerxx);`

Comment: you said I will replace scanf with fgets? right? how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading answers with the wrong `scanf` format: `%s` reads a word from `stdin` and stores it to the `char` array for which it recieves a pointer.  You pass the address of a single `char`. You should write:

```
char answer1;

scanf(" %c", &answer1);
if (answer1 == 'A' || answer1 == 'a')
    score++;
```

And so on for all the other answers.

Note that `score` should be defined as an `int` and initialized to `0`.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int score = 0;
    char answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, answer5;
    char answer6, answer7, answer8, answer9, answer10;
    char answer11, answer12, answer13, answer14, answer15;
    char answer16, answer17, answer18, answer19, answer20;
    char answer21, answer22, answer23, answer24, answer25;

    printf("\nDirection: Choose the letter of the correct answer");
    printf("\n \n1. What is the REAL name of BILL GATES?");
    printf("\nA. William Henry Bill Gates III \tB.Steve Jobs  \tC. William Henry Bill Gates  \tD. William Henry Bill Gates II");
    printf("\nAnswer?");
    scanf(" %c", &answer1);
    if (answer1 == 'A' || answer1 == 'a') score++;
    printf("\n2. Bill Gates was born in?");
    printf("\nA.Washington DC \tB. Seattle, Washington \tC. United States of America \tD. Los Angles, California");
    printf("\nAnswer?");
    scanf(" %c", &answer2);
    if (answer2 == 'B' || answer2 == 'b') score++;
    printf("\n3. Who was the Co-Founder of Windows?");
    printf("\nA. Ray Allen \tB. Paul Allen  \tC. Patrick Allen \tD. Leandro Allen");
    printf("\nAnswer?");
    scanf(" %c", &answer3);
    if (answer3 == 'B' || answer3 == 'b') score++;
    printf("\n4. When did the first WINDOWS launched?");
    printf("\nA. December 20, 1985 \tB. October 20, 1985 \tC. November 20, 1985 \tD. December 31, 1998");
    printf("\nAnswer?");
    scanf(" %c", &answer4);
    if (answer4 == 'C' || answer4 == 'c') score++;
    printf("\n5. What is the REAL name of STEVE JOBS?");
    printf("\nA. Steven Paul  Jobs \tB. Paul Leandro Lanot \tC. Steven Paul Jobs II \tD. Steve Paul Jobs");
    printf("\nAnswer?");
    scanf(" %c", &answer5);
    if (answer5 == 'A' || answer5 == 'a') score++;
    printf("\n6. Three states of matter.");
    printf("\nA.density, volume and weight  \tB. solid, liquid, and gas \tC. water, metal and gases \tD. water, air and gases");
    printf("\nAnswer?");
    scanf(" %c", &answer6);
    if (answer6 == 'B' || answer6 == 'b') score++;
    printf("\n7. The temperature at which a substance changes from a liquid to a gas.");
    printf("\nA. Freezing point   \tB. Melting point \tC.Boiling point \tD. Condensation point");
    printf("\nAnswer?");
    scanf(" %c", &answer7);
    if (answer7 == 'C' || answer7 == 'c') score++;
    printf("\n8.The temperature at which a substance changes from a liquid to a solid");
    printf("\nA. Freezing point \tB.Boiling point \tC. Melting point \tD. Condensation point");
    printf("\nAnswer?");
    scanf(" %c", &answer8);
    if (answer8 == 'A' || answer8 == 'a') score++;
    printf("\n9. Anything that has definite volume but no definite shape.");
    printf("\nA.  Solid  \tB. Metal \tC. Liquid \tD. Gas");
    printf("\nAnswer?");
    scanf(" %c", &answer9);
    if (answer9 == 'B' || answer9 == 'b') score++;
    printf("\n10. The amount of space something takes up.");
    printf("\nA. Density \tB. Volume \tC. Mass \tD. Length");
    printf("\nAnswer?");
    scanf(" %c", &answer10);
    if (answer10 == 'B' || answer10 == 'b') score++;
    printf("\n11. The temperature at which a substance changes from a gas to liquid.");
    printf("\nA. boiling point \tB. condensation point \tC. freezing point \tD. melting point");
    printf("\nAnswer?");
    scanf(" %c", &answer11);
    if (answer11 == 'B' || answer11 == 'b') score++;
    printf("\n12. The temperature at which a substance changes from a solid to a liquid.");
    printf("\nA. Condensation point \tB. boiling point \tC. freezing point \tD. Melting point");
    printf("\nAnswer?");
    scanf(" %c", &answer12);
    if (answer12 == 'D' || answer12 == 'd') score++;
    printf("\n13. Which of Newton's Three Laws does the following statement satisfy? For every action there is an equal and opposite reaction.");
    printf("\nA. Newton's First Law \tB. Newton's Second Law \tC. Newton's Third Law \tD. All of the above");
    printf("\nAnswer?");
    scanf(" %c", &answer13);
    if (answer13 == 'C' || answer13 == 'c') score++;
    printf("\n14. Which of Newton's Three Laws does the following statement satisfy? Every object in a state of uniform motion tends to remain in that state of motion unless an external force is applied to it.");
    printf("\nA. Newton's First Law \tB. Newton's Second Law \tC. Newton's Third Law \tD.  All of the above");
    printf("\nAnswer?");
    scanf(" %c", &answer14);
    if (answer14 == 'A' || answer14 == 'a') score++;
    printf("\n15. Which of Newton's three laws does the following example illustrate? If you have a hockey puck sliding along a table, it will eventually come to a stop.");
    printf("\nA. Newton's First Law \tB. Newton's Second Law \tC. Newton's Third Law \tD.  All of the above");
    printf("\nAnswer?");
    scanf(" %c", &answer15);
    if (answer15 == 'A' || answer15 == 'a') score++;
    printf("\n16. In the following example, what are the forces that are acting on the ball? Check all that apply. If a ball is thrown in the air, it will keep going the same velocity unless a force changes the velocity (speed and direction).");
    printf("\nA. air friction \tB. gravity \tC. resistance of the ground \tD. all of the above");
    printf("\nAnswer?");
    scanf(" %c", &answer16);
    if (answer16 == 'D' || answer16 == 'd') score++;
    printf("\n17. Which law states the need to wear seatbelts?");
    printf("\nA. Newton's First Law \tB. Newton's Second Law \tC. Newton's Third Law \tD.  None of the above");
    printf("\nAnswer?");
    scanf(" %c", &answer17);
    if (answer17 == 'A' || answer17 == 'a') score++;
    printf("\n18.What is another name for the Newton's first law of motion?");
    printf("\nA.Law of Acceleration \tB.Law of Velocity \tC.Law of Inertia \tD.Law of Mass");
    printf("\nAnswer?");
    scanf(" %c", &answer18);
    if (answer18 == 'C' || answer18 == 'c') score++;
    printf("\n19.Which of Newton's Three Law does the following example illustrate? The blood in your head rushes to your feet when riding on an elevator this is descending and abruptly stops. ");
    printf("\nA. Newton's First Law \tB. Newton's Second Law \tC. Newton's Third Law \tD.  None of the above");
    printf("\nAnswer?");
    scanf(" %c", &answer19);
    if (answer19 == 'A' || answer19 == 'a') score++;
    printf("\n20. A triangle with one angle greater than 90 degrees.");
    printf("\nA. equilateral triangle \tB. obtuse triangle \tC. acute triangle \tD. isosceles triangle");
    printf("\nAnswer?");
    scanf(" %c", &answer20);
    if (answer20 == 'B' || answer20 == 'b') score++;
    printf("\n21. A triangle with all three angles less than 90 degrees.");
    printf("\nA. equilateral triangle \tB. obtuse triangle \tC. acute triangle \tD. isosceles triangle");
    printf("\nAnswer?");
    scanf(" %c", &answer21);
    if (answer21 == 'C' || answer21 == 'c') score++;
    printf("\n22.A triangle with one angle equal to 90 degrees.");
    printf("\nA.right triangle \tB.equilateral triangle \tC. acute triangle \tD. isosceles triangle");
    printf("\nAnswer?");
    scanf(" %c", &answer22);
    if (answer22 == 'A' || answer22 == 'a') score++;
    printf("\n23.A triangle having three equal sides.");
    printf("\nA. equilateral triangle \tB. obtuse triangle \tC. acute triangle \tD. right triangle");
    printf("\n23.Answer?");
    scanf(" %c", &answer23);
    if (answer23 == 'D' || answer23 == 'd') score++;
    printf("\n24.The sum of the measures of all three sides of a triangle.");
    printf("\nA.area \tB. perimeter \tC. diameter \tD.none of the above");
    printf("\nAnswer?");
    scanf(" %c", &answer24);
    if (answer24 == 'B' || answer24 == 'b') score++;
    printf("\n25.In right triangle, the side opposite to right angle is called");
    printf("\nA. altitude \tB.hypotenuse \tC. angle bisector \tD.none of the above");
    printf("\nAnswer?");
    scanf(" %c", &answer25);
    if (answer25 == 'B' || answer25 == 'b') score++;

    printf("\n\t\tTEST Score=%d\n", score);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How can I initialize it by 0?

Comment: `int score = 0;`  You should start learning C from scratch with a good tutorial.

Comment: WOW THANK YOU VERY MUCH :D

Comment: @PaulLanot: You need to work on this. Try changing this program into a generic quiz where the questions and answers are stored in an array.

Comment: How can i store it in array?

Comment: Teaching you the C language basic types and structures is beyond the scope of StackOverflow.  Look for a C tutorial online and learn from scratch.